# How do you measure phase resistance and inductance of a three-phase BLDC motor without a DMM or LCR?

Tags: ac, brushless-dc-motor

I need to measure the phase resistance and inductance of a BLDC motor using circuitry without multimeters. I'm not getting the the proper solution for this. Can someone help me out to get the solution?

Comment: Welcome! Why not buy an LCR meter or build it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't state which controller is being used for the three-phase BLDC motor.

Taking the example of the TI [MCF8316A](https://www.ti.com/product/MCF8316A) *40-V max, 8-A peak, sensorless FOC control 3-phase BLDC motor driver*, the [MCF8316A Tuning Guide](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sllu335a/sllu335a.pdf) describes the use of a MPET software tool to measure motor parameters:

> The Motor Parameter Extraction Tool (MPET) will attempt to measure the motor resistance, inductance, and Motor BEMF constant (Ke) and populate these parameters automatically during the initial position detect (IPD) and open loop stage as the rotor speed attempts to accelerate. It usually takes around 10-15 seconds to estimate motor resistance, inductance and Motor BEMF constant Ke.

> The MCF8316A has Motor parameter extraction tool (MPET) which estimates the motor phase resistance, the motor phase inductance and the motor Back-EMF constant. Go to “Control Configuration - Motor parameter
> extraction tool (MPET)”.

The MCF8316A [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/mcf8316a.pdf) shows this motor controller has built-in current sensing and voltage measurement using a 12-bit ADC which are used for the *Motor Parameter Extraction*:

[image]

Therefore, consider the use of a motor controller which can measure the attached motor parameters, without needing a DMM or LCR.